# Setting a Liferay Journal Article Template as default

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, web-content

I have a liferay Journal Article (Web Content) structure, and this structure is available globally as well as one template using this structure. We are now using this structure in several sites and almost all of our sites have additional templates using this structure.

Is there a way to set one of the templates as default for this site ? So that our editors don´t always have to change the templates after they have created a new Web Content ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: You have only on structure and multiple separate templates for sites and you want to set that one structure and template (of relevant site) as default when adding new content, right?

Comment: Exactly. 1 structure and 8 templates. Site A should have template A as default when creating new web contents

Comment: For, that you will require to over-ride `\html\portlet\journal_content\view.jsp ` file. Search for `var="addArticleURL"`, pass `<portlet:param name="structureId" value="<%= ddmStructure.getStructureKey() %>" />` as URL parameter, where `ddmStructure` is the populated object for your desired structure.

Comment: yea, that´s what I feared ;)

Comment: And that's the only way I think.